# Finding $a^b \pmod m$ where $b$ is large

Tags: number-theory

Normally one would use Euler's Theorem for evaluating $a^{b} \pmod m$ where $m$ and $a$ are coprime, but what about when they are not coprime?

Mainly, what about when $b$ is too large to store directly? For example I have 2^((N+1)^2) mod M but (N+1)^2 is too large to write out.

Comment: @JavaMan I am talking about when b is too large

Comment: Are you asking for a paper-and-pencil method when $b$ is large? Because if $b$ is too large for your computer to store, I am not familiar with how it could perform even a single computation with it.

Comment: N can be 10^211 and M can be 10^6 (just choosing numbers randomly here)

Comment: @anon b can be represented as (N+1)^2 and I am curious if there is a way to reduce b before doing standard a^b mod m with squaring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Euler's Theorem is by no means the best way to calculate the remainder of $a^b$ modulo $m$ when $m$ is large. This is the case already when $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime. For to know $\varphi(m)$, one probably has to know the prime factorization of $m$. But any of the many variants of the [Binary Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) for exponentiation works well.

However, if you want to use Euler's Theorem, here is a suggestion.

We can express $a$ as $a_0 q$, where $a_0$ and $m$ are relatively prime. we need to compute $(a_0q)^b$ modulo $m$. The $a_0^b$ part is straight Euler's theorem.

So we work with the $q^b$ part. Let $m=m_0m_1$, where $m_0$ is relatively prime to $q$. If $b$ is at all large, we will have $q^b\equiv 0\pmod{m_1}$. And $q^b$ is easy to compute modulo $m_0$. Now we can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to compute $q^b$ modulo $m$.

Comment: In this case, b is too large to write out directly

Comment: For the particular sort of example you mentioned explicitly, such as $(10^{211}+1)^2$, one can do it. We want the remainder of division by $\varphi(m)$. Expand the square. We get $10^422+10^{212}+1$. Deal say with $10^{422}$. The remainder of this modulo $\varphi(m)$ can be computed by the Binary Method.